# Are there any academic articles on how people handle their passwords?

Tags: passwords, password-management, academia

Are there any academic articles on how people handle their passwords - how many they use in total, how often they change it, whether they commonly store it somewhere or just remember them and so forth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Research: A large scale study on password habits

http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=74164

Or google "password user habits" for examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly about password management, it focuses on password creation. I thought that you could find it useful anyway: http://www.imperva.com/docs/WP_Consumer_Password_Worst_Practices.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a lot of academic work in the area of password selection, prominent papers include:

[Yan et al 2000](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-500.pdf),  [Kuo et al 2006](http://repository.cmu.edu/isr/36/) and [Bonneau and Preibusch 2010](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejcb82/doc/password_thicket_bonneau_preibusch.pdf)

Joseph Bonneau from Cambridge University has done a lot of work in this area including the final paper above and
http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jcb82/doc/BS12-USEC-passphrase_linguistics.pdf,
he is a regular contributor to the [Cambridge University Computer Laboratory Security Research blog](http://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org) which is a good source for papers on passwords and proposals for replacing them.

Answer (score 1):

The book [Security and Usability by Garfinkel and Cranor](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596008277.do) has relevant chapters from researchers in the field:

- Chapter 1: Psychological Acceptability Revisited investigates the effort investment that passwords, patching etc require, and how much investment can be requested before people give up and try to subvert the system.
- Chapter 6: Evaluating Authentication Mechanisms looks at the more general field of investigating the usability of authentication techniques.
- Chapter 7: The Memorability and Security of Passwords is probably exactly what you want ;-)
- Chapter 9: Graphical Passwords investigates that alternative.

Answer (score -3):

You should probably get a good hash function and you can just store it, on a database. Because a good enough hashed password will tell you no information about your password.
Also attempted passwords you can count that, but the other information seems irrelevant imo.

Comment: The question is more about statistics on how users handle their passwords - how many of them use one password everywhere, how many of them vary it and so forth